# Removing python

Tags: python

I removed python from my computer to be reinstalled. However after removing it, many services has gone from my Ubuntu 10.04. (e.g. mozilla, Ubuntu Software Center and many applications from System tab.) How can I get back all of them? Thanks a lot..

Comment: what command did you use for uninstalling python

Comment: I guess all of these services depend on python. You can get them back by installing python.

Comment: I used sudo apt-get remove python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the code written in Ubuntu is written in `Python`. One should avoid removing system dependencies at any time.

You can do `sudo apt-get install python` but rest of the programs are probably gone; even though you install them manually, you can experience random bugs, system failures. I think you should just re-install ubuntu

Comment: Ahh, I think there should be a warning for inexperienced people like me. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Do extremely careful when using `sudo` espeically on removing things. `sudo` means superuser-do, which means increase access level to root, which means you can do anything.